# Moving svn working copy to another computer

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm in the process of moving from an old laptop to a new one.

Am I able to just move my client copy of the svn repository from the old laptop to the new?  Note that it has files in it that I'm not able to commit yet.

So effectively I want to move \\old-laptop\c$\myDev to become \\new-laptop\c$\myDev

Is this possible?

(I've searched for similar answers but I think they all refered to moving folders within a repository or moving the server repository.)

Comment: Quick aside: what you're talking about here - "client copy of the svn repository" - is usually called a "working copy".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly fine. It might break if you install an older version of svn/Tortoise on the new computer than you were using on the old (an earlier minor version, i.e. 1.4.xx not 1.6.xx), but assuming you set up the new laptop with the latest Tortoise it'll all just work.

I'm not 100% sure if there are line ending problems moving your working-copies between Windows and Linux, though, but doesn't sound like you're doing that.

Alternatively, you could create a temporary branch and commit your work-in-progress to that? Then you'd be sure of not losing it.

Comment: +1 for the temporary branch. Having "files in it that I'm not able to commit yet" is not an acceptable practice, IMO.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not finding this to be the case for me that I can just move the working copy. Perhaps there are restrictions about the new computer being the same OS version or architecture (32 bit/64 bit)?

Comment: @Jessica I think I wrote that way back for 1.6.x and things have changed for 1.7.x but I think everything should still just work. The working copy data directory layout has changed, and most of the data has been moved into a SQLite database but SQLite say their databases are [number of bits and endianness independent](http://www.sqlite.org/about.html). I can certainly use 32-bit clients on a repository checked out with a 64-bit client etc. As always though your best bet is probably to create a new temp branch, check your working copy into that and get a fresh checkout on the new machine.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. Even if you are still afraid of losing something you can copy first, not move, and check if everything is in one piece.